# XSLT samples which support param values

Tags: xslt, osb

context: from OSB to xslt call. Please help with the samples to support the below requirement.

I am looking for a sample xslt file, which will take multiple param values from OSB.

From OSB I want to pass four parameter values to an xslt function, will have to take four attribute values in the input message($body) if any of them matches to the passed value, then it should return true other wsie false.

Suppose, my param values to be passed to xslt are mango, carrot, pepsi, venilla, and in the input xml the sections are such as

```
<fruits fruit="apple" .../>
    <vegetables vegetable="tomato".../>
    <drinks drink ="cola" ... />
    <icecreams icecream="vanilla"/>
```

only in the input if the values passed from OSB to xslt are present in any of the respective attribute, then it should return true other wise false.

```
Thanks.
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What should the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please note the xsl:param tag and the $ tag which indicates that I am using the parameter. This is a working XSLT is some code that I have written.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:ns3="com.namespace3" xmlns:ns7="com.namesapce7" xmlns:ns23="com.namespace23">
  <xsl:param name="ParamName"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns7:SourceXMLRoot>
      <ns23:interactionId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns7:request/ID"/>
      </ns23:interactionId>
      <ns23:processId>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ParamName/ns3:ParamRoot/ID"/>
      </ns23:processId>
    </ns7:SourceXMLRoot>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```